# Properly mapping stateToProps with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to the react-redux paradigm for projects and I am a little confused on the concept of mapping state to props. I created a store with an initial value:

```
export function initialState() {
    return { priceRange:[0,10000] }
}
```

Then in my child component I mapStateToProps like so:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { onPriceRangeChange }
const mapStateToProps = {priceRange}  = ({
    value:priceRange
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeMap)
```

The problem is that it's getting a `'priceRange' is not defined no-undef` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Use ({priceRange}) => so that you destructure the props into your arrow function.

Comment: Do your have your app wrapped in the `react-redux` `<Provider>` component?

Comment: I have the root of my app wrapped in `<Provider store={store}>..</Provider>`

Answer (score 0):

Missed `mapStateToProps`

Add :

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have to define your `mapStateToProps`, as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ priceRange }) => ({
    value: priceRange
})
```

It's the same as:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    value: state.priceRange
})
```

This technique is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a `>` after the `=` of state.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { onPriceRangeChange }
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   value: state.reducerFile.priceRange
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeMap)
```

If that still doesnt work, see the below if you are using combineReducers();

---

### combineReducers()

Are you using redux `combineReducers()` method? If so, you so you will need to get to your values one level deeper.

```
// reducer.js
export function initialState() {
    return { priceRange:[0,10000] }
}

//store.js
import { initialState } from './reducer.js';
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';

export default createStore(
  combineReducers({
    reducerFile: initialState
  })
);
```

Then in your child component, you will get it like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { onPriceRangeChange }
const mapStateToProps = state  => ({
   value: state.reducerFile.priceRange
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeMap)
```